# How to send attachment in email with devise?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise

In my controller file:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout "devise"
  before_action :check_url, only: [:new]

  def create
    attachments["logo.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/images/logo.png")
    super
  end
end
```

In my view file:

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url %>
```

After than I am getting this error,

> undefined local variable or method `attachments' for

Comment: I want to send registration mail to user and in that i want to add logo image in mail template.

Comment: @pulkit Agarwal  this is not worked for me :(

Comment: post your controller code here

Comment: @PardeepSaini you can see controller code in que i just edited it.

Comment: Is not your `attachments` like a local variable? Try changing all its occurrences to `@attachments`

Comment: @Sinstein after doing this getting error like this 

undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass @attachments["logo.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/retina/logo.png")

Comment: Okay. Since you are using `@attachments` as a hash, maybe declare it before you assign values to it. Try and put  `@attachments = {}` or `@attachments = Hash.new` before you set `@attachments["logo.png" = ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding devise create method is not good solution. you can write callback for this .

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  after_create :send_admin_mail
  def send_admin_mail
    UserMailer.send_new_user_message(self).deliver
  end

  # ...
end
```

and your user mailer should look like

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def send_new_user_message(user)
   @user = user
   @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
   attachments.inline['image.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/image.jpg')
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

Comment: I implemented this same but i can't see image in mail template.

Comment: can you share you git repo or gist, so i can check what's going wrong there?

Comment: this is working fine for me. I was blocked image attachment in my gmail account. thnx